# How to validate password from asp.net in js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, passwords, jquery-form-validator

I have this input:

### aspx

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" data-fv-stringlength-min="5" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" pattern="password" title="Follow the password requirement"/>
```

### js

```
if( pattern ){
   var regex, jsRegex;
   switch( pattern ){
       case 'alphanumeric' :
          regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i;
          break;
       case 'numeric' :
          regex = /^[0-9]+$/i;
          break;
       case 'phone' :
          regex = /^\+?([0-9]|[-|' '])+$/i;
          break;
       case 'password':
          regex = /^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "])+$/i;
              break;
     }
}
```

the password case doesn't works fine. when I click on the password field and type any letter, it stuck and I can't enter any letter !

### edit

in aspx, i use the following script:

```
<!-- validator -->
    <script>
      // initialize the validator function
      validator.message.date = 'not a real date';

      // validate a field on "blur" event, a 'select' on 'change' event & a '.reuired' classed multifield on 'keyup':
      $('form')
        .on('blur', 'input[required], input.optional, select.required', validator.checkField)
        .on('change', 'select.required', validator.checkField)
        .on('keypress', 'input[required][pattern]', validator.keypress);

      $('.multi.required').on('keyup blur', 'input', function() {
        validator.checkField.apply($(this).siblings().last()[0]);
      });

        //$('#add_member_form').formValidation();


      $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var submit = true;

        // evaluate the form using generic validaing
        if (!validator.checkAll($(this))) {
          submit = false;
        }

        if (submit)
          this.submit();

        return false;
      });
    </script>
    <!-- /validator -->
```

### Note:

I am using free bootstrap template. therefore, all the code is written in the template and I try to edit it to suite my need and try to understand it.

### Edit2 : pattern code is in validator.js "coming with the template"

```
var validator = (function($){
var message, tests;
message = {
        invalid         : 'invalid input',
        email           : 'email address is invalid',
tests = {
email : function(a){
            if ( !email_filter.test( a ) || a.match( email_illegalChars ) ){
                alertTxt = a ? message.email : message.empty;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
},
text: function (a, skip) {
if( pattern ){ // pattern code },
number : function(a){ // number code // },
date : function(a){ // date code // },
```

Comment: Could you please provide all validate function seems like your function will erase password field on each keyDown event or something like this

Comment: This issue is a direct duplicate of your first issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907982/how-to-validate-password-field-in-bootstrap . don't do this, just edit the original question

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not clear, and need more details

## First, choose a method

Actually, you have two options to get what you want to do.

**HTML5, using a pattern attribute**

Many input types are able to manage their own pattern
(like email, phone, password...)
You must specify the pattern into the attribute "pattern",
without delimiters /.../ (and options)

```
<input 
   type="password" 
   id="password"
   name="password" 
   data-fv-stringlength-min="5" 
   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" 
   required="required" 

   pattern="^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? \"])+$" 

   title="Follow the password requirement"/>
```

*But be careful with escaping quotes that can collide with the attribute quotes*

**JS, from a control javascript**

*Since i don't understand what are ou doing with your 'incomplete' code (above in you post).
I suppose, you have defined some `onKeyDown` events on inputs to catch when user is writing and calling the actual code under a function ?
I don't see the required condition to match the inputs values !
Can you update your post with more details, and i'll update mine too.*

---

## If you choose to continue with you plugin

Okay, in concerne of your edit2, using i guess jquery.form.validator:

```
var validator = (function($){
var message, tests;
message = 
{
   invalid : 'invalid input',
   email   : 'email address is invalid',
};

tests = 
{
    // <input type="email">
    email : function(a)
    {
        if( !email_filter.test( a ) || a.match( email_illegalChars ) )
        {
            alertTxt = a ? message.email : message.empty;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },

    // this is for <input type="text">
    text: function (a, skip)
    {
        if( pattern ){ // pattern code },
    },

    // this is for <input type="number">
    number : function(a){ /* number code */ },
    date : function(a){ /* date code */ },

};
```

Then, i think you have to add you password method to tests:

```
// this is for <input type="password">
password: function (a, skip)
{
    if( pattern ){ /* pattern code */},
},
```

---

## Or i propose to you, a more simple

And not plugin requiring solution, by reusing your original code
from your (first duplicate post) [How to validate password field in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907982/how-to-validate-password-field-in-bootstrap)

note: stop using `removeClass(...).addClass(...)`, would prefer 
short and relevant methods like `toggleClass(classname, condition)`
or `switchClass(classbefore, classafter)`

**CSS**

```
.invalid { color: red!important; } /* note this important flag is require to overwrite the .valid class */
.valid   { color: lime; }
```

**HTML hint**

```
<div id="pswd_info">
  <h4>Password requirements:</h4>
     <ul>
       <li id="letter" class="fa-warning"> At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
       <li id="capital"> At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
       <li id="number"> At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
       <li id="special"> At least <strong>one special character</strong></li>
       <li id="length"> Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
       <li id="password"> Must contains at least <strong>8 characters</strong>, specials chars (#$!...) and numbers</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("form input").on("keyup", function(event)
{
    var invalidClass = "invalid";
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(type)
    {
        case "email": /*  */ break;
        case "phone": /* */ break;
        case "number": 
        {
            var smt = (/^\d$/i.test(val);
            $('#number').toggleClass(invalidClass, smt);
            break;
        }

        case "password": 
        {
            var smt = (/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/i.test(val);
            $('#password').toggleClass(invalidClass, smt);
            break;
        }
    }
}).on("focus", function()
{
    $('#pswd_info').show();

}).on("blur", function()
{
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

Comment: I try your first solution, I stuck in the text box and can't write anything

Comment: ok, then forget first solution. i need more: Where is located your first script if(pattern)... , how is defined pattern variable ? Is in validator.keypress ?

Comment: Put the complete code of your first snippet please.
On second snippet, is suppose you are using jquery.form.validator ? i'm  true ?

Comment: Ha! ok, you if(pattern) is located specifically for input of type "text" (text: function (a, skip) {.... if(pattern)... Then try to add a method named "password". Like : password: function(a, skip) { /* and put your regex tests here */ })